# Javascript Custom rounding approach for decimal

Tags: javascript

Input number is `21.2791499`. I need to round it in 4 decimal places and expected output in is `21.2792`, But all the following approaches give `21.2791` as output. What is the best solution to get the desired output.

```
The number "9" after number "4" should make the number "4" as "5". Then this "5" should make "1" as "2"
```

Good or bad, my client’s browser is `IE6+` only.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/16mgy0xm/1/

```
var inputNUmber = 21.2791499;

//Approach 1
var a = Math.round(inputNUmber * 10000) / 10000; 
document.getElementById("firstText").value= a;

//Approach 2
var b = Number(Math.round(inputNUmber+'e4')+'e-4');
document.getElementById("secondText").value= b;

//Approach 3
var c =inputNUmber.toPrecision(6);
document.getElementById("thirdText").value= c;
```

Comment: So to be clear, you don't want to round to the nearest integer, you want to always round up?

Comment: ummm you do know that the number 4 rounds down right?

Comment: What does "round from the last integer" mean? You can generally round up, down, or to the nearest integer.

Comment: The number "9" after number "4" should make the number "4" as "5". Then this "5" should make "1" as "2"

Comment: There is no method of rounding that works that way. You'd need to roll your own by working digit by digit through that logic. But unless you have very unusual specific requirement that's a very strange way of rounding numbers.

Comment: @Lijo that is not how "rounding" works, i suggest you take a math class :)

Comment: _"Input number is `21.2791499`. I need to round it in 4 decimal places and expected output in is `21.2792`"_  Why would `21.2791499` mathematically round to `21.2792` ?

Comment: this question is off topic, please read and study how rounding numbers work http://www.factmonster.com/math/numbers/rounding.html

Answer (score 3):

So to be clear, you don't want to round to the nearest integer, you want to always round up?

In which case `Math.ceil(21.2791499 * 10000) / 10000 = 21.2792`

Scale the number up by the required number of decimal places, use the built in ceil function, and then scale it back down.

Comment: Isn't this kind of dangerous considering the floating point math is so finicky?  For instance, `Math.ceil(21.27910000000001 * 10000) / 10000` results in `21.2792`, but `Math.ceil(21.279100000000001 * 10000) / 10000` results in `21.2791` on my version of chrome.

Comment: Well any floating point maths breaks when you add enough decimal places. So yes, but what can you do.....

Comment: but that is not rounding anything, just setting the last integer up one, "OP" does not understand what "rounding" means so this answer may still be correct.

Comment: @JamesGaunt I suppose you're right.  I guess it's more of a problem with the OP's premise.

Comment: Yes, this answer isn't answering the question being asked, but it's probably answering the question the OP should be asking.

Comment: @JamesGaunt classic xy problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution.  It still suffers from floating point math inaccuracy to a point.

Basically it always "rounds" up unless the value has exactly four decimal places.

```js
var inputNUmber = 21.2791499;

//Approach 1
var a = Math.round(inputNUmber * 10000) / 10000; 
document.getElementById("firstText").value= a;
 
//Approach 2
var b = Number(Math.round(inputNUmber+'e4')+'e-4');
document.getElementById("secondText").value= b;

//Approach 3
var c =inputNUmber.toPrecision(6);
document.getElementById("thirdText").value= c;

// Here's my approach
var d = Math.floor(inputNUmber * 10000) / 10000
d += +(d < inputNUmber) / 10000;
document.getElementById("fourthText").value= d;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="firstText"/>
<br />
<input type="text" id="secondText"/>
<br />
<input type="text" id="thirdText"/>
<br />
<input type="text" id="fourthText"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `String.prototype.split()` , `String.prototype.slice()` , `Array.prototype.splice()` , `Array.prototype.join()` , `Math.round()`

```js
var inputNumber = 21.2791499;

// split value at `.` character
var n = String(inputNumber).split(".");
// portion of number after `.` character
var k = n[1];
// convert numbers after `.` to array
var res = k.slice(4).split("");
// add `.` at index `1` of numbers following `.` character
// of original input number; e.g., convert `2791499` to `2791.5`
res.splice(1, 0, ".");
// results
var input = document.getElementById("firstText");
// use `Math.round()` , `.slice()` , `.join()` on resulting number
// following insertion of `.` character
input.value = Math.round( k.slice(0, 4) + "." + Math.round(res.join("")));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="firstText"/>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/16mgy0xm/6/

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution to your weird rounding issue https://jsfiddle.net/16mgy0xm/5/

**ESSENTIALLY ALL I AM DOING IS ROUNDING THE NUMBER TWICE**

see example 1 I am dividing `var a` after setting `var a` this sets the value to round at the 5th decimal place, using the second `math.round()` i am them setting it back to the 4th decimal place to give you your desired effect.

```
var inputNUmber = 21.2791499;

//Approach 1
var a = Math.round(inputNUmber * 100000) ;
a = a / 100000;
var a1 = Math.round(a * 10000) / 10000;
document.getElementById("firstText").value= a1;
```